# Find and replace partial string in dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I currently have two dataframes that have been pulled from CSV files that I need to join. Problem lies in the fact that the join column isn't matching and there are many files I must go through, so manual cleaning in excel isn't optional.

Here is what I am working with...

DF1

```
ID     Title      HIF
1      A          HIF-1101
2      AB         HIF-1102
```

DF2

```
HIF               Date      Type
HIF-1101 CD42     01/12/19  Image
HIF-1102 JH96     01/14/19  Image
```

I need to eliminate the extra letter/number combo in DF2. All rows in join columns(there are a few thousand) carry the same number format in 'HIF-XXXX'. Maybe there is a way to find 'HIF' and then index 5 characters to the right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `str.extract` to extract the pattern `HIF-\w{4}` from `df2['HIF']`, you can then merge `df1` and `df2` together on "HIF".

```
df1.merge(df2.assign(HIF=df2['HIF'].str.extract(r'(HIF-\w{4})')), on='HIF')

   ID Title       HIF      Date   Type
0   1     A  HIF-1101  01/12/19  Image
1   2    AB  HIF-1102  01/14/19  Image
```

Comment: Safer and more general answer than mine, +1

Comment: @Erfan Err on the side of caution! Btw, returned the upvote.

Comment: agree, mine would fail if there are whitespaces for example.

Comment: Thanks guys! I had no idea \w even existed. Y'all teach me something new every day.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`pandas.Series.str.slice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html)

```
df2['HIF'] = df2['HIF'].str.slice(stop=-5)
print(df2)
        HIF      Date   Type
0  HIF-1101  01/12/19  Image
1  HIF-1102  01/14/19  Image
```

Then merge

```
df_merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='HIF')
print(df_merge)
   ID Title       HIF      Date   Type
0   1     A  HIF-1101  01/12/19  Image
1   2    AB  HIF-1102  01/14/19  Image
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using `str.find`

```
df2.HIF=df2.HIF.str.findall('|'.join(df1.HIF.tolist())).str[0]
df1.merge(df2,on='HIF')
Out[73]: 
   ID Title       HIF      Date   Type
0   1     A  HIF-1101  01/12/19  Image
1   2    AB  HIF-1102  01/14/19  Image
```